# Ambitious Networking Project for iOS, need direction

Tags: ipad, networking, ios, web

I'm challenging myself to write an app I know nothing about in 2 months time and I need some direction. Suppose you wanted to create an awesome iPad app that takes craigslist posts and displays them in a neat fashion. How would I gather the information from craigslist.org using Objective-C/C in xCode? What objects would I be interacting with to create network connections and how would that information be read in? Would I be reading the source code?

Thank you!

Comment: @Mitch, that's why I gave him a vague answer that provides no code, but at least I hint that he should do the google.  Also, $20 says he's <16

Answer (score 0):

Craigslist has RSS feeds, so I suppose you could just get the link, parse the feed, and display it on a table.  There are too many examples to count out there on how to do that.